# how to hide "infoFiltered" option in the datatable plugin in jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatable

In the datatable plugin have a option like "infoFiltered". This one is used to show how many rowsin the datatable in all pages.But i don't want to show how many rows in the datatable.So,how to hide that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you're asking about `sInfoFiltered` option. To hide that,

set `oLanguage.sInfoFiltered` to blank as shown below.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#example').dataTable( {
       "oLanguage": {
         "sInfoFiltered": ""
       }
     } );
   } );
```

[**Documentation**](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n#oLanguage.sInfoFiltered)

Comment: i tried infoFiltered: "_TOTAL_" == 0 ? " " : ("_TOTAL_") but this not working.